# Maintain Tab Name on Return from SSH

Tags: macos, shell, ssh, zsh

I use multiple terminal tabs, which I manage with names on the tabs. Thus, I have tabs named "python", "workspace", etc. One of these tabs is for an SSH connection to my remote machines, which is named "ssh".

The problem is that when I ssh into a remote machine, the tab name is changed to reflect the identity of the machine into which I'm SSH'd. This is good. However, when I come back to my local machine, the tab name is not reset to "ssh", nor is it reset to the default tab name (what appears when I open a new tab - I even have a customized version of this defined in my `~/.zshrc`).

Is there a way I can reset the tab name when I come back to localhost by terminating an SSH connection?

Technical Details:

- OS: Mac OS X 10.9.2
- Shell: zsh

Relevant parts of `~/.zshrc`:

```
source ~/.zsh_functions
tabn "ashwin@cortana"
```

Relevant parts of `~/.zsh_functions`:

```
function tabn {
  printf "\e]1;$1\a"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a pair of [`xterm` escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (recognized by most terminals as well) that can save and restore the window title. The following command would push the current window title on to the stack:

```
printf '\e[22;2t'
```

and this would restore it:

```
printf '\e[23;2t'
```

You could define a function that wraps `ssh` to automatically save the current title and restore it after `ssh` completes:

```
ssh () {
    # If you redirect the output of ssh to a file or a pipeline,
    # make sure these terminal sequences go to the terminal, not
    # standard output.
    printf '\e[22;2t' > /dev/tty
    command ssh "$@"
    printf '\e[23;2t' > /dev/tty
}
```

As with any stack, this assumes that anything pushed on the stack on the remote end is popped off before `ssh` exits.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not get me my terminal-tab's title back. Any thoughts on how I could fix that?